# Keyboard shortcut though different screens/spaces?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut, spaces

[image: Picture of the launch service]So far I haven't found a solution to this minor nuisance, hopefully it's easier than I think.

I have two monitors, each with its own spaces. I run two apps on monitor 1, which I use more frequently and three other apps on monitor 2.
I have created an Automator launch service to which I have assigned a keyboard shortcut, to easily move between my two apps on monitor 1 (without having to reach for the trackpad and click on the app window). That works really well, however it is not recognized when I'm in one of the apps in monitor 2. At first I thought it was the apps, but now I think it's actually a space/screen problem.

Any workarounds you can think of?

Thanks

EDIT: it does work from Safari on monitor 2, but not from Excel 2011 and from a dictionary app. The latter has hardly any keyboard shortcuts of its own, so it shouldn't be a conflict problem (I went for cmd+alt+K, which I do not think does anything in Excel either).

Comment: Could you show us what the Automator launch service does & how you’re triggering it.

Comment: I have added a picture of the Automator service, as you can see it's very very simple. My second app on Monitor 1 is Microsoft Word 2011, which I go back to by a mouse click because there I use a mouse anyway.

Comment: For completeness of info, in case you were wondering how this helps me. I trigger this Automator service with a keyboard shortcut, which in turn gets triggered by a smart button (Flic button), which allows me to transcribe from a VLC file easier (I have added other shortcuts to the Flic button too, but this part is beyond the scope of my original question, just background info for anyone interested in achieving anything similar).

Comment: All I can think of, to eliminate Spaces itself as the cause, is to try again with Mission Control > "Displays have separate Spaces" disabled [It will mess up your existing Spaces layout, so I don't want to test it myself]

Comment: Thanks @Tetsujin. I think I'll wait with that too, I have a good setup now and separate spaces work better for me than one big space comprising two monitors (I have had that before). I'll give it a try once I'm done working on this project. As I said, minor nuisance, but I was trying to understand if there's any fix. Thanks anyway!